# Why does none of click or change event trigger my function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement

Well i checked the jQuery documentation and according to it i can do something like:

```
function notifyme(){
    console.log(true)
}
$('button').on('click', notifyme );
```

Which is correct. But my code doesn't seem to work.

Here's what i have in my code. I have a div with an id `myinput` like so:

```
<div id="myinput">
    <input type="checkbox" value="0"/>
</div>
```

And this is my jQuery code:

```
$('#myinput input').on( 
    'change', 
    My_fn( $(this).prop('checked') )
);

My_fn( theVal ){
    if( theVal == true ){
        console.log(true)
    }
    else{
        console.log(false)
    }
}
```

Even when i try:

```
$('#myinput input').on( 
    'click', 
    My_fn( $(this).prop('checked') )
);
```

I get no console log.

Interestingly if i place this code at the beginning of the script:

```
My_fn( $('#myinput input').prop('checked') )
```

I get a console log of `true` since the checkbox is checked.

Why does none of `click` or `change` event trigger the `My_fn()` function ?

**Answer**
I got it.

Firstly i removed the parameter for the function when using on. So this 
`My_fn( $(this).prop('checked') )` becomes this `My_fn()`. Now when using `.on()`. I simply wrote

```
$('#myinput input').on( 
    'click', 
    My_fn
);
```

And it worked. Thanks to anyone who helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below code . it is wrong to pass $(this).prop('checked') as param in function.

```
$('#myinput input').on( 
    'click', 
    My_fn
);

My_fn(){
  if( $(this).prop('checked')== true ){
    console.log(true)
  }
  else{
    console.log(false)
  }
}
```

or you can use is() selector to check weather check box is checked or not

```
My_fn(){
  if( $(this).is(':checked') == true ){
    console.log(true)
  }
  else{
    console.log(false)
  }
}
```

Comment: $(this). will assign inside function not as param .

Comment: for more understand you can read http://api.jquery.com/on/ again ..and check what function get as argument

Answer (score 1):

Declare the function first.
When you do a `.on()` you are already sending a reference of the input element to the event handler (My_fn) so effectively you don't have to send a parameter to the function. Instead in the function handler try to get the properties of the element.

Try something like this

```
function My_fn(theVal){
  if( $(this).is(':checked') === true ){
    console.log(true)
  }else{
    console.log(false)
  }
}
$('#myinput input').on('change', My_fn);
```